# Get complete hierarchy of azure blob structure based on prefix

Tags: azure, blob, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

I have following hierarchy in my azure storage container :

```
Container  
-- Folder 1  
  -- Folder 2  
     -- Folder 2.1  
       -- File 1  
       -- File 2  
       -- File 3
```

What I'm searching for is a generic function where I can pass string e.g. "container/Folder1/Folder2" and it return me the hierarchy i.e.

```
-- Folder 2.1  
   -- File 1  
   -- File 2  
   -- File 3
```

I have following code in place but in this I'm not able to pass the prefix as "container/Folder1/Folder2". If I add "/" in prefix string then it throws error that invalid uri string.

```
    static void printCloudDirectories(IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobList, Container cont)
    {
        foreach (var blobitem in blobList)
        {
            if (blobitem is CloudBlobDirectory)
            {
                var container = new Container();
                var directory = blobitem as CloudBlobDirectory;
                Console.WriteLine(directory.Prefix);
                container.Name = directory.Prefix;
                BlobContinuationToken token = null;
                var directories = directory.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(token).Result.Results;
                printCloudDirectories(directories, container);
                cont.Containers.Add(container);
            }
            else
            {
                cont.Children.Add(blobitem.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void ListClientMethod(CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient)
    {
        BlobContinuationToken token = null;
        var containerSegments = cloudBlobClient.ListContainersSegmentedAsync(token).Result;
        List<Container> containers = new List<Container>();
        foreach (var container in containerSegments.Results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Container: " + container.Name);
            var cont = new Container();
            cont.Name = container.Name;
            // ADD A CALL TO printCloudDirectories:
            BlobContinuationToken token1 = null;
            var blobs = container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(token1).Result.Results;
            printCloudDirectories(blobs, cont);
            containers.Add(cont);
        }
    }
    public class Container
{
    public Container()
    {
        Children = new List<string>();
        Containers = new List<Container>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<string> Children { get; set; }

    public List<Container> Containers { get; set; }
}
```

I use c# as coding language

Comment: Please edit your question and include what language SDK (including version) you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use [`ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(String, Boolean, BlobListingDetails, Nullable<Int32>, BlobContinuationToken, BlobRequestOptions, OperationContext)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobssegmentedasync?view=azure-dotnet-legacy#Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlobContainer_ListBlobsSegmentedAsync_System_String_System_Boolean_Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_BlobListingDetails_System_Nullable_System_Int32__Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_BlobContinuationToken_Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_BlobRequestOptions_Microsoft_Azure_Storage_OperationContext_) method.

The 1st parameter to this method is the `Blob Prefix` and you need to specify `Folder 1/Folder 2/` there.

2nd parameter to this method is `useFlatBlobListing` and you need to pass `true` for that.

It should return you a result like:

```
Folder 1/Folder 2/Folder 2.1/File 1
Folder 1/Folder 2/Folder 2.1/File 2
Folder 1/Folder 2/Folder 2.1/File 3
```

and you should be able to construct the desired treeview based on this.